# Using overloaded operators on this instance (this) within a class method

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am writing a class for a 2D Vector and need to do a dot product.

I have overloaded the `*` operator to do this, but when it comes time to perform `this * this` it gives me an error:

```cpp
class Vector2 {
private:
    float x, y;
public:
    Vector2(float _x, float _y) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }

    // Dot product
    float operator*(const Vector2& other) {
        return x * other.x + y * other.y;
    }

    // Magnitude (abs)
    float Magnitude() {
        float dot = (this) * (this); // HERE IS THE ERROR: expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type
        return std::sqrt(dot);
    }

    Vector2 operator+(const Vector2& other) {
        return Vector2(x + other.x, y + other.y);
    }
};
```

The error is: *expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type*

Any help is appreciated! Thank You :)

Comment: modify to (*this) * (*this)?

Comment: `this` is a pointer, multiplying pointers makes no sense.

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't realise that the 'this' keyword was a pointer. I'll keep that in mind :))

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword is a pointer, not an actual object.

The correct code is therefore `(*this) * (*this)`.

Comment: This is not an answer. You already said thanks in the comments. You can answer your own question, but this is not useful for any future readers.

Comment: It's not? I mean, if anyone else had this issue, they would see that `this` is a pointer, not a reference / object. Also, thanks for your amazing input :)

Comment: With some rewording it is basically an answer